# Black-Scholes formula producing a negative number for a Call Option

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

I would expect that the Black Scholes model should always give a value for a call option, $c$, to be at least $0$. However, I am seeing some cases where that is not the case. Here is the Black-Scholes model for a call option.
\begin{eqnarray*}
c &=& S_0 N(d_1) - Ke^{-rT}N(d_2) \\
d_1 &=& \frac{ \ln{ \frac{S_0}{K} } - (r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2})T }{\sigma \sqrt{T}} \\
d_2 &=& d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now please consider the special case of $\sigma = 0.1$, $T = 1$, $r = 0$ and $K = 2S_0$. We have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
c &=& S_0 N(d_1) - Ke^{-(0)(1)}N(d_2) = S_0 N(d_1) - 2S_0N(d_2) \\
d_1 &=& \frac{ \ln{( \frac{S_0}{2S_0} )} - (0 + \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(1) }{\sigma \sqrt{1}} \\
d_1 &=& \frac{ \ln{( \frac{1}{2} )} - (0 + \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(1) }{ 0.1 } \\
d_1 &=& 10 \ln{( \frac{1}{2} )} - 10\Big( \frac{.01}{2} \Big) \\
d_1 &=& 10 \ln{( \frac{1}{2} )}  - \frac{.1}{2} \\
d_1 &=& -6.9814718 \\
N(d_1) &=& 0.000000000001461 \\
d_2 &=& -6.9814718 - 0.01 \sqrt{1} = -6.9914718 \\
N(d_2) &=& 0.000000000001360 \\
c &=&  S_0 (0.000000000001461) - 2S_0 (0.000000000001360) \\
c &=&  (-1.259E-12) S_0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Why am I getting a negative number? Is it round off error?
Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your $d_1$ is wrong - the minus sign is wrong. It should be:
$$
d_1 = \frac{\ln(S_0/K) + (r+\sigma^2/2)/T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}.
$$
See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model).

Comment: re: Your d1 is wrong - the minus sign is wrong. It should be:
d1=(ln(S0/K)+σ2/2)/σ. Where is the T factor?
Isn't the equation $$\frac{\ln(S_0/K)+(r+\sigma^2/2)T}{\sigma\sqrt T}$$

Comment: @David I think you're right, please provide an edit with the proper $\LaTeX$ formatting. Of course, in this example we have $T=1$ and it doesn't matter but it might be confusing to readers.

Comment: Thanks @David I edited my answer so that it is fully clear.,